# The index of DataFrame lost its name after append a row

Tags: python, pandas

After add a new row of DataFrame, the name of index has lost in Pandas 0.15.1.
This didnot happen in pandas 0.14.1.
It is a bug or a feature?

```
In [4]: import pandas as pd

In [5]: pd.__version__
Out[5]: '0.15.1'

In [6]: fra = pd.DataFrame(data={'age': [10,20,30], 'height': [100, 170, 175]}, index=pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], name='Tag'))

In [7]: fra
Out[7]: 
     age  height
Tag             
a     10     100
b     20     170
c     30     175

In [8]: fra.loc['d'] = 35, 172

In [9]: fra
Out[9]: 
   age  height
a   10     100
b   20     170
c   30     175
d   35     172

In [10]: fra.index.name

In [11]: print fra.index.name
None
```

Comment: This looks like a bug and happens whether using `ix` or `loc` if you append e.g. `df.append(pd.Series([35,172]), ignore_index=True)` then the index name is preserved, this also happens on `0.15.2`